# Unable to figure out what's happening here in $http.get - Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm a newbie to **Angular JS**. I was referring Online tutorials and came across the $http service.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("ngClassifieds") // referring module which is already created
        .controller("classifiedsCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

            $http.get('data/classifieds.json')
                .then(function(classifieds){
                    $scope.classifieds = classifieds.data;

                })
        });
})();
```

> In this piece of code, I'm not able to figure out these lines. Can
>   anyone explain what actually happens here ?
>
> ```
>   $http.get('data/classifieds.json')
>      .then(function(classifieds){
>          $scope.classifieds = classifieds.data;
>      }
> ```

I have this [data](https://github.com/chenkie/ngclassifieds/blob/End_of_Section_7/data/classifieds.json) in my `data/classifieds.json` file.

My question is, what exactly the `data` referred in `classifieds.data` is ?

- what does `classifieds.data` represent here ?
- what information does it contain?
- what would be the result which we assign to `$scope.classifieds`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Good job for reading a tutorial, that is a start... 1) See [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) its right there at the top with big bold letters. 2) did you go to the file `data/classifieds.json` you reference in your copy/paste link and code? (*it helps to read what you copy/paste, open it up and see what is inside*). 3) that variable now has a reference to the returned data that was received in the call back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$http returns a promise, it's an asynchronous call, angular use a fork of a library called Q for promises, you can see $q documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q.
When the promise is fulfilled, that means, the asynchronous call is complete, the .then method call success or error callback depending on the result of the async call.

> .then(successCallback, [errorCallback], [notifyCallback]) – regardless
>   of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls
>   one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the
>   result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument:
>   the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may
>   be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before
>   the promise is resolved or rejected.

The argument passed to the success callback is an object with the information about the request response. The `data` property contain the body of the response, in other way, all the content of `data/classifieds.json` file (in your case), therefore, `$scope.classifieds` will contain the json returned by `data/classifieds.json`.

Here a friendly article about promises and $q: http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/

Answer (score 1):

A simple get request example from [AngularJS Docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

In your code,

```
$http.get('data/classifieds.json') // This is the URI of your json file
     .then(function(classifieds){ // Success callback
         $scope.classifieds = classifieds.data; // Here, you are assigning response's data into $scope.classifieds
     }
```